# How to determine css-class-wrapper programmatically in Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

`liferay-portlet.xml` file allows `<css-class-wrapper>` tag inside `<portlet>` tag.

Is it possible to determine it's content programmatically in portlet class or JSP?

Comment: By determine its content, you mean to say you want to get value of it in jsp?

Comment: @PankajKathiriya yes true

Answer (score 4):

You can get it by code below

```
Portlet portlet = (Portlet)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.RENDER_PORTLET);
String cssClassWrapper=portlet.getCssClassWrapper();
```